# MySQL Updating database error

Tags: mysql, database

Im trying to get it so when you press a button it updates the value of 'subscribe' to 1 but for some reason its not working.

```
<?php
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['userID'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
require '../../core/connect.php';

if ($_SESSION['userID']) {
    if (isset($_POST['subscribe'])) {

        $query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `subscribe`='1' WHERE `username`='".$username."'") or die(mysql_error());

        if ($query2) {
            header("Location: /index.php");
        } else {
            echo "An error occured. Your subscription failed! Please try again later.";
        }
    }else {
        echo "Error occured.";
    }
}else {
    echo "No session found.";
}
?>
```

The error im getting is the 'Error occured.'

The field is an int with the default value as 0

Thanks!

Comment: but the button that leads to this action is called 'subscribe' as defined in the isset.

Comment: $_POST['subscribe'] isn't set... Check your button name, and whether you're using post or get. use print_r($_POST); to see the post array

Comment: Yeah thanks, had a mindblank moment there. Was looking at the wrong value and not name lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Error Occurred' implies

```
if(isset($_POST['subscribe'])) // is evaluating to false
```

use

```
print_r($_POST) // and post the result
```

Comment: Wow.. i was looking at my code thinking 'its called subscribe!!' i was looking at the value, not the name. facepalm.. thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

`if(isset($_SESSION['subscribe']))`